# Rails 3 passing parameters between non-secure and secure pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

This seems like a pretty straight-forward question, but Google is failing me.

My currently all-SSL site needs to be only partially secure (it's not search engine friendly otherwise). But while I want my home page to be unsecure, there's a form on that page that does go to a secure page. As things stand, any form parameters going to a secure site are lost, causing the usual mayhem.

What is the best practice for this situation? In terms of my setup, I'm using rack-ssl-enforcer gem for Rails 3 (works beauty, btw). But these secure and non-secure pages need to co-exist somehow.

Thanks!
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure i get the point, but why don't you use the :except or :only option:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only   => /^\/admin\//
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :except => /^\/home\//
```

Then, use the :protocol option for your form, e.g.

```
# PagesController#home
%h1 Home
= render 'comments/form'

# CommentsController#_form
= form_for @comment, :url => comments_path, :protocol => https
  ...
```

That should do the trick...